# How to setup 3 level menu layout in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-menu

I am trying to implement a menu which has 3 levels.

Each level has 5 items.

First level : A,B,C,D,E,
Second Level: 1-5,
Third level: 1-5

Swiping up & down changes the menu level. Swiping left & right changes the selected item in the current menu level. The currently selected item should always be in the middle.

The picture probably explains best what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

1. How should I setup/build this layout?

My thoughts were:

```
Linear Layout
  RecyclerView
     ListItems<A-E>
  RecyvlerView
     ListItems<1-5>
  RecyvlerView
     ListItems<1-5>
```

2. How can I highlight the currently selected menu level?
3. How can I highlight the currently selected item?
4. How can I make the RecyclerView only scroll one item by one swipe?
5. How can I start the RecyclerView "in the middle" of the screen? (as shown for menu level 2)
6. How can I make all 3 RecyclerViews only listen to gestures and not to scrolling each of them? Only the active menu level may be changed. To change another menu levels item, one has to change to that menu level first by swiping up/down.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is too much for one post. Start with one question one post, tackle it, then move on to the next.